# Sypder is crashed....any solution to recover it?

Tags: python, spyder

I have tried to install virtual environment...after installing that my Spyder is not at all opening and anaconda prompt also. I have tried uninstalling anaconda and tried deleting all files of anaconda and reinstalled it but my problem is not solved. While opening Anaconda prompt also it produces this error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pavig\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "c:\users\pavig\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
  File "c:\users\pavig\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 12, in <module>
    GenericAlias = type(list[int])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It appears that you are using Python < 3.9 but loading the `python39` built-ins. Check your `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to remove this directory `c:\users\pavig\appdata\local\programs\python` and then use `conda` to create your virtualenv and also `conda` to install Spyder (instead of `pip`).